# maps constants on each connected component of an open set.

Tags: general-topology

In a book , I find the following passage :

For example, if $A$ is a topological abelian group (e.g., $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ ), then we can define a sheaf on any topological space $X$  by setting $\mathcal{F} (U)$ equal to the set of continuous maps and taking the restriction maps to be the usual restriction of functions. When $A$ has the discrete topology, every continuous map $ f : U \to A$ is constant on each connected component of $U$ , and hence factors through $ \pi_{0} (U) $ the space of connected components of $U$. When this last space is discrete, $ \mathcal{F} (U)$ is the set of all maps $\pi_0 (U) \to A$ , i.e., $\mathcal{F}(U) = A^{ \pi_{0} (U) }$. In this case, we call $\mathcal{F}$ the constant sheaf defined by the abelian group $A$.

My question is :

How to establish that $f$ is contant on each connected component of $U$ using proof by contradiction ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It's pretty much the definition of a *connected* component. Do you know the definition of "connected"?

Comment: The image of a connected space under a continuous function is connected. What are the connected subspaces of a discrete space?

Comment: @Najib Idrissi : Yes, $X$ is connected means that : $ \forall U,V \ $ two open subsets of $X$ : $ X = U \bigcup V $ and $ U \bigcap V = \emptyset \ \Longrightarrow \ X = U $ and $ V = \emptyset $.

Comment: @Serveas : The connected subspaces of a discrete space are singletons.  :-)

Comment: Let $V$ a connected component of $ U $ , and suppose that $ f $ which is continuous on $ U $, is not constant on $ V $ , then $ \exists x, y \in V $ such that : $ f (x) \neq f (y) $ then : $ f^{- 1} ( \{ f (x) \} ) $ and $ f^{- 1} ( \{ f (x) \}^c) ) $ with : $ y \in f^{- 1} ( \{ f (x) \}^c) $ is a partition of $ V $ in two open disjoint , it means that: $ V $ is not connected , which is absurd. Therefore $ f $ is constant on $ V $ , Is it correct ? Thank you. :-)